# Index Operators and lists in Python

Tags: python

i am currently learning Python basics in a course on our university, there is one question which i am currently not able to answer : 
The task is :

Change the variables on the first section, so that every if command will be solved as True, you should get a 1-3 listed if you run the code.

```
# Change the Code below here
number = 10
first_array = [5, 6, 7, 8] 

# If code
if number > 15:
    print("1")

if len(first_array) == 5:
    print("2")

second_array = ["one", "two", first_array]
if second_array[2][3]+3 == 10:
    print("3")
```

---

I tried to use this Code :

```
# Change the Code below here
number = 16
first_array = [7, 0, 0, 0, 0] 

# if code
if number > 15:
    print("1")

if len(first_array) == 5:
    print("2")

second_array = ["one", "two", first_array]
if second_array[2][3]+3 == 10:
    print("3")
```

Can someone explain to me how exactly second_array[2][3]+3 will be solved? I tried googling with Index Operators but couldnt find the correct answer to help me with this problem.

Comment: Since `second_array[2]` itself is an array, that statement is basically saying `if first_array[3]+3 == 10`.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I always thought i have to think about the second_array as : ["one", "two", [7, 0, 0, 0, 0]], but i have to see it as ["one", "two", first_array] right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually Python lists.

A list in Python can contain anything as its member, and different members can be of different types.

This line:

```
second_array = ["one", "two", first_array]
```

builds a list with 3 members: two strings, and the entire `first_array` as its 3rd member.

You are probably thinking that it combines two lists giving you this:

```
[ "one", "two", 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

but that is not correct!

What you really get is:

```
[ "one", "two", [ 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

A list within a list, or array inside the array.

That is why this line:

```
if second_array[2][3]+3 == 10:
```

Has two indexes, each in its own set of brackets []
The first (from the left) is for the outer list, and the second is for the inner list.

You could also write it like this:

```
member = second_array[2]
if member[3] + 3 == 10:
```

Try putting `print member` after the first line and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, i understood it now. It was exactly as you said, i thought the list were combined into a new list since i am just starting and did not think about this.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `second_array = ["one", "two", first_array]` then the values of `second_array` become `["one", "two", [7,0,0,0,0]]`.

Because of this, `second_array[2][3]` can be read as "second_array's third element's fourth element" (cause of the 0-based indexing).

So the second_array[2][3] is the element marked by x:
`["one", "two", [7,0,0,X,0]]`

Answer (score 0):

`first_array[3]+3 == 10`
<=>
`first_array[3] == 7`

so with `first_array = [7, 0, 0, 7, 0]` , the test condition will answer True

Comment: Your answer should reference `second_array` to answer OP's question.